# Animation flickering at the end

Tags: jquery, css, animation, width

EDIT: Fixed the animation by removing the CSS transition.

I actually have two problems. The first is at the end of the width animation the UL flickers. I'm not sure why and can't seem to fix.

The second is I'm trying to get the UL onto the same line as the . Is there a way to change the animate function so it adds `display:inline-block` instead of `display:block`?

```
// toggle filters
$(".filter .toggle").on('click', function(){
    $('.filter').find('.toggle').toggleClass('test').end()
                .find('ul').animate({width:'toggle'}, 1000);
});


.filter {
    padding-left:25px;
    padding-bottom:10px;
    width:500px;
}

.filter * {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear; -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear; -o-transition: all 0.2s linear; transition: all 0.2s linear;
}

.filter .toggle.test {
    padding:7px;
    color:#eee;
    background-image: linear-gradient(bottom, #272527 31%, #2f2c2e 66%, #373435 83%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #272527 31%, #2f2c2e 66%, #373435 83%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #272527 31%, #2f2c2e 66%, #373435 83%);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #272527 31%, #2f2c2e 66%, #373435 83%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #272527 31%, #2f2c2e 66%, #373435 83%);
    font-size:15px;
    border-radius:5px 0 0 5px;
}

.filter .toggle {
    font-size:11px;
    border-radius:5px;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    cursor:pointer;
    background:rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
    padding:4px;
    line-height:14px;
}
    .filter .toggle:before {
        font-family:icon;
        content:'\f0c9';
        padding-right:5px;
        color:#888;
    }

.filter ul {
    display:none;
    height:18px;
    vertical-align:top;
    overflow:hidden;
    background:white;
}

.filter li {
    display:inline-block;
    padding-right:10px;
    font-size:16px;
}

<div class="filter">
   <span class="toggle">Filters</span>
   <ul>
     <li class="active">All</li>
     <li>One</li>
     <li>Two</li>
     <li>Three</li>
     <li>Four</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Here's [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6rCTX/) - click 'filters.'

Comment: I can't seem to see any flicker. Maybe browser-specific?

Comment: Chrome, but I fixed it by removing the CSS transition (I forgot jQuery animate doesn't need it.)

Comment: add `float:left;` to `.filter .toggle` and `.filter ul`

Comment: You healed yourself :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of this line in your CSS and everything should work just fine

```
.filter * {
-webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear 0;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s linear;
    transition: all 0.2s linear;
}
```

By the way, this is a browser-specific issue. It affects Chromium (maybe Webkit), but not Firefox or Opera. Unable to test in IE and Safari. Removing the above animation will just solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

There is a conflict between the animation and the CSS transition.  If you remove the CSS transition rules, it seems to work without flickering (specifically a transition on the `width` rule).

If you still need transitions for some other reason, just be more specific about which ones.  I can't tell based on the CSS, but something like:

```
transition: border-radius .2s linear, padding .2s linear;
```

By the way you probably only need `-webkit` and non-vendor at this point.